# What are some arguments opposing the criminal justice system reform?

Tags: united-states, judiciary

As in, the idea that there should be major changes to the criminal justice system because of its high incarceration rate and high racial disparity. I'm researching the criminal justice system reform and I'm having a difficult time finding any arguments that oppose it. ([source](https://www.prisonpolicy.org/reports/pie2017.html))

Comment: I'm sorry, but in order to name arguments against a proposal you would need to tell us what exactly the proposal is. You write "major changes to the criminal justice system" but not what exactly those changes are. It could mean longer sentences, shorter sentences, introduce some alternative forms of punishment, more sentences, less sentences, less racial profiling, a racist might even suggest more racial profiling. Please edit your question to describe the exact changes you would like to hear arguments against.

Comment: I would think that *inertia* ("the status quo is fine!"), indifference ("why should we worry about making jail more comfortable, it's for *punishment*?") and a *tough on crime* approach ("we need to lock the *bad people* away!") are major factors that resist change, even if they aren't an articulate argument against specific reforms. You may have to broaden the way you approach your research.